# retrieve mysql data using 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

for example i have 3 fields in my search DAY, MONTH, YEAR
the user must select it independently or  all together like

DAY/MONTH

DAY/YEAR

MONTH/YEAR

DAY/MONTH

DAY/MONTH/YEAR

```
inputs: day month year
method: GET
```

select must search in any column with all combinations

table

```
     id  |     day  |   month  |   year
  ---------------------------------------
     1   |    10    |    jan   |   2013
     2   |    25    |    jun   |   2013
     3   |    02    |    jan   |   2015

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day = $day or month = $month or year = $year;
```

if my month = jan should return 1 and 3

if my my day = 10 and year = 2013 should return 1

and so on

it doesn't work... it only matches with one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably facing a problem with `NULL` values.  This may be what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ($day is null or day = $day) and
      ($month is null or month = $month) and
      ($year is null oryear = $year);
```

This assumes that "missing" values are `NULL`.  You may have some other representation (say an empty string), in which case change the logic accordingly.

Comment: the user should be able to make any combination with those inputs selecting 1, 2 or 3 of them

Comment: @EddieD. . . . The structure of this `where` clause allows you to choose any combination of `$day`, `$month`, and `$year`.  Modify your question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: i've tried some combinations and nothing happened, for example `$day` can be `$_GET['day']` right? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Eddie D. debug your php code to see if you have an connection with MySQL... better place some php code and an create table statement and some example data here we can't geuss what your problem is we need facts..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i gonna edit my question..take a look if it explains better.. and yes. i have connection

Comment: @GordonLinoff i solved my problem.. i used your sql but i've changed to `(day is not null and day = $day) or (month is not null and month = $month)...  it worked :) thank you`